# Command line style caret for Textbox in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How can I change the textbox blinking caret as command line style caret ie. horizontal cursor in textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateCaret(textBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 10, textBox1.Height);
    ShowCaret(textBox1.Handle);
}
```

Comment: @NitinKabra this worked for me, but as soon as I clicked on the textbox, the normal caret was restored.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below sample code.

```
this.Cursors = Cursor.None;
this.cursors = cursor.pointer or cursor.arrow
```

Comment: well I am not talking about the mouse cursor, I am taking about the textbox blinking cursor ..

Comment: Please correct `Cursor.Pointer` and `Cursor.Arrow`. C# is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using code like the following (thanks to Prabhakantha).  I had to use a timer to set the cursor after handling the textbox Enter event:

```
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        CreateCaret(textBox1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 6, textBox1.Height);
        ShowCaret(textBox1.Handle);
    }
```

This seems a little hackish, though.  There must be a better way.